# Want to make user login on button click with out using asp login control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make user login after he has sign up .My problem is that after user has signed up and enter details I want to make him login automatically.But when i make user login in code , Login status and login name is not showing anything ie, user has not logged in.

My code for making user login is as under:

```
   subl.LoadByLogin(ds, txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());


   //  bool rememberUserName = LoginUser.RememberMeSet;



    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
       {

   SessionContext.SystemUser = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SystemUser"], 0);
   SessionContext.SystemUserX = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"] + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"];
  SessionContext.SuperAdministrator = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsSuperAdmin"], false);
   SessionContext.SiteAdministrator = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsSiteAdmin"], false);
   SessionContext.IsTravelAgent = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsTravelAgent"], false);
    SessionContext.TravelAgentID = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TravelAgentID"], 0);
     SessionContext.IsMember = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsMember"], false);
     SessionContext.PropertyID = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PropertyID"], 0);
  SessionContext.MemberID = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MemberID"], 0);
  SessionContext.RegID = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RegID"], 0);
   SessionContext.Site = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Site"], 0);
  // SessionContext.Reseller = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PropertyName"].ToString();



   if (SessionContext.SuperAdministrator)
    {
      // SessionContext.SiteAdministrator = true;
         }
   // SessionContext.IsPublisher = WebHelper.Cast(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsPublisher"], false);

         //Initialize FormsAuthentications
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, SessionContext.SystemUserX, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50), false, "Sparrow", FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", true);
```

in Login1_Authenticate before calling Response.redirect(somewhere.aspx);

It'll set the user as logged in. You can get username by accessing the textbox for username in the login control.